# Why doesn't file.write() store bytes in the sequence I have given ? c++

Tags: c++

Short:
I want to write data byte for byte in sequence to a file.
The data is transfered to the file with file.write. 
But when I review the file with hexdump the written data is not in sequence.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    // array with four bytes I want to write 
    // This should be 0x01020304 in memory
    char write_arr[4]={1,2,3,4};

    // int with four bytes I want to write
    // I use little endian so this should be 0x04030201 in memory
    int write_num=0x01020304;

    std::ofstream outfile;

    outfile.open("output.txt",std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);

    if( outfile.is_open() ) {
        outfile.write( write_arr ,sizeof(write_arr)/sizeof(char) );
        outfile.write( reinterpret_cast<char *>(&write_num),sizeof(write_num) );
        outfile.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I use hexdump on the output it displays this:

```
0201 0403 0304 0102
```

The bytes have been rearranged.

I expect the output to be:

```
0102 0304 0403 0201
```

Why is the rearranging happening ?

And how can I achieve a transfer where the bytes are in sequence ?

Comment: How are you doing the hexdump? You should dump bytes, not words.

Comment: `od -t x1` to dump by char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hexdump dumps 2-bytes words; not individual characters.
That is what is confusing you - try

```
od -t x1
```